# add multiple numbers in batch

Tags: batch-file

i try to add two numbers received from a file.
But it shows only the last value of sum. Thx for the help!

```
@FOR /F "eol=; tokens=1-3 delims=, " %%i IN (test.txt) DO (  
   set m=%%j   
   set n=%%k  
   set /a sum=%m%+%n%  
   echo sum = %sum%  
   )
```

and in the test.txt i have

```
alex 4 5  
john 6 7
```

and i want to see

```
sum=9  
sum=13
```

it only shows

```
sum=13  
sum=13
```

Comment: You failed to note one tiny detail: On first run it will only show `sum = `. It's not exactl y the last value your loop shows but instead the one from before the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the percent expanding in the line `set /a sum=%m%+%n%` and `echo sum = %sum%`.
These are expanded **before** the FOR-loop is executed.

Therefore you got the result of the "global" set of sum.

It's better to use the delayed expansion, as then all variables enclosed with `!` are expanded at runtime not parsetime

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "eol=; tokens=1-3 delims=, " %%i IN (test.txt) DO (  
   set m=%%j   
   set n=%%k  
   set /a sum=m+n
   echo sum = !sum!
)
```

Comment: @Alex: Note also that the variables `m` and `n` are referenced without using either `%` or `!` around their names on the line that calculates `sum`. This special way of referencing is allowed in `SET /A` command and it has the effect of delayed expansion (i.e. it works as if you referenced them like this: `set /a sum=!m!+!n!`).